# `is` comparison: direct object comparison vs. comparison of object identity representation

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am getting the following results:

1. `() is ()` returns `True` (comparison between two objects)
2. `id(()) is id(())` returns `False`. (comparison between the representations of object identities)

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> The ‘is‘ operator compares the identity of two objects; the id() function returns an integer representing its identity.

Given case (1), object `()` has the same identity (*memory address*) as object `()`; but in case (2), the representations of their identities are not identical to each other.

Why is that?

Comment: So you should compare the `id`s with `id(()) == id(())`... Use `==` not `is`.

Comment: Because the ids are large integers that exist twice in memory. Only small integers are cached in CPython.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I understand that the `id()` returns integers but was confused about why they were different *objects* since they are the representations of the same object.

Comment: @timgeb good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @timgeb btw, can you add it in the answer below so I can vote it up? thanks! Also, I was curious how large is 'large', and [answers from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) say that anything >256 counts as *large* and anything <=256 is treated as literals

Answer (score 1):

The `id(..)` function returns **an integer** that represents the "identity" of an object so to speak. Although it is true that if two variables `x` and `y` refer to the *same* object, `x is y` succeed, and the result of `id(x)` is equal to `id(y)`, that **does not mean those integers themeselves are the same object**.

You thus should use:

```
id(()) == id(())
#      ^ == not is
```

In Python, even `int`s are objects, and although usually there is a *cache* such that small integers indeed refer to the same object, the following test will usually fail:

```
>>> 1234567890 is (1234567891-1)
False
>>> 1234567890 == (1234567891-1)
True
```

Comment: "and therefore in some cases, the id(..) of an object could change between two calls". I'm fairly sure this is false: it would defeat the whole point of `id`. Do you have any references for this claim?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: sorry I misread the documentation. The id is indeed guarnateed to be constant during an objects lifetime. (dowside of *speedreading* :( )

Comment: The part about the memory address possibly changing _is_ true, though, for some implementations (e.g., PyPy), which means that PyPy has to jump through hoops to have a constant `id` (which is of course _not_ based on memory addresses). CPython never moves objects around in memory, so using the memory address for the `id` is safe.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the explanation!